# Como acceder a la info de un carrito Prestashop desde una página externa

Tags: vue.js, prestashop, get

Necesito acceder a la información del carrito de un Prestashop, desde un página externa a este Prestashop, en este caso desde un plugin Wordpress que solicita por GET esa info del carrito, comento:

**Instalación de Prestashop (http://localhost/prestashop)**

Aquí he creado un módulo que lo hace es devolver cierta información para que el plugin de Wordpress la consuma, dentro del módulo, en /front/controllers/ he creado un archivo info.php con el siguiente código:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../../init.php');

class ApiCartInfoModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

  public function __construct($response = array()) {
    parent::__construct($response);
    $this->display_header = false;
    $this->display_header_javascript = false;
    $this->display_footer = false;
  }

  public function postProcess(){

    $product = new Product(1);

    $newCart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);

    $data = array(
      "id_cookie_cart" => $this->context->cookie->id_cart,
      "nameProduct" => $product->name[1],
      "total"  => strval($newCart->getOrderTotal()),
      "static_token" => Tools::getToken(false),
      "token" => Tools::getToken()
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
  }

}
```

Si accedo a esta url https://localhost/prestashop/module/apicart/info, puedo ver perfectamente la salida del array por pantalla:

```
{"id_cookie_cart":"15","nameProduct":"Camiseta efecto deste\u00f1ido de manga corta","total":"56.76","static_token":"3455435gfdgdfg4545435","token":"454435dfdfrgf4354545fg"}
```

El problema viene cuando desde Wordpress con Vue realizo una petición GET a esa url para obtener el mismo objeto JSON, hay ciertos datos del objeto que no obtengo correctamente.

**Instalación de Wordpress (http://localhost/wordpress)**

Aquí he creado un plugin que carga Vue y mediante una petición GET por Fetch:

```
var url ="http://localhost/prestashop/module/apicart/info";
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
  }
  fetch(url,options)
  .then((response) => {

    return response.json();

  }).then((data) => {

    console.log(data);

  })
```

En el console.log que hago de data, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{id_cookie_cart: false, nameProduct: "Camiseta efecto desteñido de manga corta", total: "0", static_token: "3455435gfdgdfg4545435", token: "454435dfdfrgf4354545fg"}
```

Como podéis ver, los valores de *id_cookie_cart* y de *total* no los llego a recoger, que son los que más me interesan, pues mi intención es poder consultar el carrito de Prestashop desde Wordpress con VUE en este caso.

Todo lo que intento devolver desde $this->context lo obtengo desde Vue como 0, false, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas intentando obtener el carrito del contexto desde el exterior, el contexto es para quien ejecuta la petición, por esa razón es que al ejecutarla en tu navegador funciona, en este caso al hacerlo desde Wordpress el contexto sería para el servidor de Wordpress y lógicamente no tiene un contexto válido ni el que estás intentando conseguir, por lo tanto lo que pretendes hacer es imposible, a menos que seas tu quien conozca y envíe el id de carrito al controlador y cargar un contexto de carrito a partir de ese id.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Rolige, he encontrado un módulo de pago por ahí que lo hace haciendo calls por ajax con Jquery. No me complico más la cabeza con esto, pero muchas gracias por la atención. Saludoos!